Append empty columns from a list to an existing dataframe
Consider this:
I have a (rather long) list of column names:
COLUMNS = [a, b, c, d]
I have a df that have some columns as in the list, and some new ones:
import pandas as pd
data = {'a': [1, 2],
        'b': [True, False],
        'z': ['hi', 'bye']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I need to create a new df that would

have all the columns from the COLUMNS list

retain the column order from the COLUMNS list

add data from df to the columns if they have same name

add the column from df that are not in the COLUMNS list at the end of the new df


Expected results:



a
b
c
d
z




1
True
-
-
'hi'


2
False
-
-
'bye'




You can compute an Index union and reindex:
COLUMNS = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

out = df.reindex(columns=pd.Index(COLUMNS).union(df.columns, sort=False))

Output:
   a      b   c   d    z
0  1   True NaN NaN   hi
1  2  False NaN NaN  bye

Example with a non-ordered input:
COLUMNS = ['zz', 'c', 'a', 'b']

out = df.reindex(columns=pd.Index(COLUMNS).union(df.columns, sort=False))

   zz   c  a      b    z
0 NaN NaN  1   True   hi
1 NaN NaN  2  False  bye

